# SQL Update with Subquery as Data source doesn´t work (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i have the following SQL DML Update command, but the syntax isn´t correct and the command doesn´t work:

```
UPDATE hmsg_vehicle_category
SET hmsg_vehicle_category.hmsg_id, hmsg_vehicle_category.vehiclecategories_inputname
SELECT l_p.hmsg_id, tmp_p_vc.inputname 
FROM hmsg_him_product AS l_p INNER JOIN (  SELECT p.id, vc.inputname
                                           FROM him_product p INNER JOIN vehicle_category vc
                                              ON p.id = vc.product
                                           ORDER BY p.id, vc.inputname DESC ) AS tmp_p_vc
    ON l_p.products_id = tmp_p_vc.id
WHERE l_p.hmsg_id = 171;
```

How can i execute this SQL command? Where is the mistake in the snytax?

Thanks for help !

Greetz
Marwief

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to update. You're not telling it which rows in `hmsg_vehicle_category` to update. You're saying `UPDATE tableA WHERE tableB.id = 171`, which to the database may as well be `UPDATE journey.Distance WHERE desk.Material = 'Wood'`, you're giving it no indication of any link between the 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
update hmsg_vehicle_category set
    hmsg_id = l_p.hmsg_id,
    vehiclecategories_inputname = tmp_p_vc.inputname 
from hmsg_him_product as l_p
    inner join him_product as p on p.id = l_p.products_id 
    inner join vehicle_category as vc on vc.product = p.id
where l_p.hmsg_id = 171
```

Be warned, this one will update all records in `hmsg_vehicle_category` table. May be you want to add this into `where` clause:

```
update hmsg_vehicle_category as hvc set
    vehiclecategories_inputname = tmp_p_vc.inputname 
from hmsg_him_product as l_p
    inner join him_product as p on p.id = l_p.products_id 
    inner join vehicle_category as vc on vc.product = p.id
where
    l_p.hmsg_id = 171 and hvc.hmsg_id = 171
```

But I cannot advice something more specific at the moment, because it's unclear from your question.